# Exception handling using excel file

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a code. What the code ideally does is:-

1. It executes the function GetTaskStatus(). There are several other similar functions in my code.
2. If an exception occurs in any function, it moves the control to ExcelRecorder() function
3. If an exception is thus caught in any of the function, I have to write FAIL inside an excel sheet, in a given row's J cell and also the exact exception error (*for ex, NullReferenceException was found*) in K cell of the same row. In short, J cell is RESULT and K cell is REMARKS. There are several rows in my excel sheet.
4. If no exception has occurred in any function, I simply need to write PASS in that given row's J cell
5. My code is able to do that. But, however there is a problem. Irrespective of whether an exception occured or not, my code is inputting FAIL and REMARKS for all the rows in my excel (though some of the functions does not cause any exception)

I have posted the main snippet of my code. Can anyone kindly let me know where I am going wrong? I need to input PASS if no exception has occurred for a function.

CODE goes below

```
public void GetTaskStatus()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invoking GetTaskStatus method");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------****-----------------");
                m_taskStatus = taskClient.GetTaskStatus(m_taskID);
                Console.WriteLine("Task status : " + m_taskStatus.taskStatus.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An exception has occured. Please check the Excel sheet for more info", "Exception Caught" + ex);
                ExcelRecorder(true, ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }


public void ExcelRecorder(bool isExceptionalData, string message)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ExcelRecorder method reached when exception occurs");
            //Code for recording into excel should be written here
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:/dsds.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
            int numSheets = xlWorkbook.Sheets.Count;
            for (int row = 2; row <= rowCount; row++)
            {
                if (isExceptionalData)
                {
                    ((Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[row, "J"]).Value2 = "FAIL";
                    ((Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[row, "K"]).Value2 = message;
                }
                else
                {
                    ((Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[row, "J"]).Value2 = "PASS";
                }
            }
            xlWorkbook.Save();
            xlWorkbook.Close(0,0,0);
            xlApp.Quit();
        }
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see why an exception is caught. Ctrl-Alt-E to bring up the Exception dialog. Check all boxes to 'break on thrown'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that `isExceptionalData` is always true, therefore this code block

```
if (isExceptionalData)
{
    ((Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[row, "J"]).Value2 = "FAIL";
    ((Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[row, "K"]).Value2 = message;
}
else
                {
    ((Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[row, "J"]).Value2 = "PASS";
}
```

is always going to go down the 'FAIL' branch

Adding this in your try will add the row accordingly when no exception occurs.

```
 ExcelRecorder(false, null);
```

Comment: yeah..it is always true...but how do i change it so that it becomes true when an exception occurs and false when an exception doesnt not occur? I tried to add it in a finally block but it is not of any use.

Comment: hi..i cant add ExcelRecorder(false, ex.Message); in my try...cos ex is declared in catch statement only..if i add ExcelRecorder(false, ex.Message); in try statement, i get an error "The term ex does not exist in the current context"...i already tried this...can u suggest something else pls???